# C keyboard library

Tags: linux, c, keyboard, keyboard-listener

I am looking for a means to register one or more buttons being pressed and/or held down on a keyboard in pure C (C90 or later), not **C++/C#**. Are there any libraries or methods to actively monitor actions on the keyboard?

For example: holding down the q key the program will print q for the entire duration of the action.

I am a C noob (using Ubuntu 16.04) and would like to learn more and expand in this area of programming. Any help or redirection for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What operating system and C compiler are you using?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm currently learning C90 so that would be best, but anything for later versions would also help heaps!

Comment: Libraries may be compiler-specific - a library that works with Microsoft's Visual Studio C may not work with GNU C. They will definitely be operating-system specific; a library that works with a C compiler on Windows will not work on Linux. _Which compiler and operating system are you using?_

Comment: @JeffZeitlin my apologies, I am using Linux, more specifically Ubuntu 16.04, and I am running everything off the generic terminal installed. (ie cc -ansi -o progam program.c)

Comment: OK, I'll defer to the Linux experts; my experience is with Windows.